# Keeping this Latex Style

Tags: overleaf, templates

I found this two-column template for research paper on Overleaf.

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/isecure-draft/tmkjrydcqbfx

I love the style of the paper and I would like to write my paper in a similar format but it seems I cannot get rid of the heading. This is the documentclass

```
\documentclass[Print]{../Style/isecure-v24}
```

Can someone help me please? If not, could someone help me locate a similar **two-column** template? Overleaf did not have good options besides this one.

Comment: why do you want to search for a similar class? simply dowload the file from overleaf

Answer (score 1):

Overleaf runs a standard texlive so if you have a project using one of their templates you can download it and use locally.

From the link you gave select <kbd>Open as Template</kbd> which gives you a project using that class.

Then in the left menu select Download <kbd>Source</kbd>

[image]

and you will get a zip file you can unzip and use locally.

Note the warnings suggest the class has serious bugs but that's a different issue.